# Откат миграций в EF CodeFirst

Tags: c#, migrate, ef-code-first

Есть некоторые файлы миграции EF CodeFirst. В таблице истории миграций вижу их, после них ещё есть автоматические миграции:

**№№ | MigrationId | ContextKey | Model | Version**

1. 20220814121219_Initialization  . . 6.4.4
2. 20220815120521_Initialization1    . . 6.4.4
3. 20220904134518_AlphabetSymbolSerialNumberAdded . . 6.4.4
4. 20220904134835_AlphabetSymbolSerialNumberUniqueAdded  . . 6.4.4
5. 20220918161906_AttributesAdded      . . 6.4.4
6. 20220921161906_AutomaticMigration      . . 6.4.4
7. 20220922161906_AutomaticMigration         . . 6.4.4

Проблема: файлы миграций есть, в таблице истории миграций они есть, вроде как, миграция прошла успешно. И вызов Update-Database сообщает, что всё ОК.
Но система не видит некоторые столбцы, которые были добавлены этими миграциями - их, действительно, нет в БД.

Пытаюсь откатить миграции, чтобы потом накатить их снова, такой командой:

*Update-Database -TargetMigration: 20220904134518_AlphabetSymbolSerialNumberAdded*

Получаю ошибку:

*The specified migration '20220904134518_AlphabetSymbolSerialNumberAdded' does not exist. Ensure that target migration refers to an existing migration id.*

В чём может быть дело? И как исправить ситуацию?

Answer (score 0):

Для отката БД к нужной миграции используйте команду:

```
Update-Database <migration-name>
```

Т.е. в вашем случае, если вы хотите откатить БД до миграции AlphabetSymbolSerialNumberAdded, команда должна выглядеть следующим образом:

```
Update-Database AlphabetSymbolSerialNumberAdded
```

Подробнее о командах можете почитать по ссылке:
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core-migration.aspx

Почему нужных столбцов в вашей БД нет?

Могу предположить один вариант - у вас была применена последняя актуальная миграция, но её впоследствии изменили.
Но так как у вас в БД она уже применена, то ваша структура БД осталась прежняя.
Такая ситуация вполне возможна на этапе разработки какой-нибудь фичи в отдельной ветке до её переноса в основную ветку разработки.